# Optional Multidimensional Arrays as Arguments in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to declare a function that has 1 required argument and 4 optional 2D array arguments, how do i do so? I know to make an argument optional, we should place a value in it during function creation.

I also saw what I did below is wrong and has a `"Array initializers can only be used in a variable or field initializer. Try using a new expression instead."` Error

```
private String communicateToServer(String serverHostname,
                               String[,] disk = new string[] {{"dummy","dummy"}},
                               String[,] hdd= new string[] {{"dummy","dummy"}}
                               String[,] nic= new string[] {{"dummy","dummy"}}
                               String[,] disk = new string[] {{"dummy","dummy"}}
)
```

Comment: Make the default value `null` instead, then in the function you can do `disk = disk ?? new string[] { .. };`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to do this directly but you can get a similar effect by doing the following pattern

```
private String communicateToServer(String serverHostname,
                                   String[,] disk = null,
                                   String[,] hdd= null,
                                   String[,] nic= null) {

   disk = disk ?? new string[] {{"dummy","dummy"}},
   hdd= hdd ?? new string[] {{"dummy","dummy"}}
   nic= nic ?? new string[] {{"dummy","dummy"}}

    ...
}
```

Essentially use `null` as the default and if `null` is the value convert to the actual default.  This does mean that an explicit `null` being passed will be interpreted as the default value though.

Comment: +1 as it's the only way I know to accomplish this but it's worth noting that this does have the side-effect of removing the ability to pass in null purposefully.

Comment: @McAden that side-effect is noted in the last sentence :)

Comment: Oh, so I can just leave a null checker instead to get to my goal, -removes dummies- if (hdd != null) { Do code with 2D Array values},
Thanks man and cheers =)

Comment: @JaredPar - oops, somehow I missed that.